# Facebook custom tab installation issue

Tags: facebook

I am developing my first application in facebook. The application installs a custom tab to a user selected page using link http://www.facebook.com/add.php?api_key=app_key&pages=1&page=fb_page_id. After the application is installed the fan page has to be loaded. Current understanding is that this will be done automatically.In this case the tab is installed successfully but the fan page is not loaded. Instead the page http://www.facebook.com/developers/login_error.php?app_id=custom_tab_appid&type=external is loaded. Couldn't identify the reason for this error. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked that the tab is actually installed on that page? I've never used that URL system to install an application into a page, I usually open the application profile with an account which has administration rights on the page and then click on the **Add to my page** link on the left sidebar.

Another possible reason is the new feature that Facebook introduced last 23th March. As users can now force Facebook to use **https** in all requests, you have to set up a **secure URL** for both canvas and tab application. **If you don't specify one, the tab will just don't appear on the page.**

You can disable this for your user account (and only yours) [here](https://www.facebook.com/editaccount.php), and then clicking on **Account security**

Comment: Yes the tab is installed on that page. The page does not get loaded after the application is installed.

Comment: Take a look at the secure settings that I have mentioned. Do you have the page URL so we can check also?

Comment: Was able to fix this issue. Setting "Canvas URL" in Facebook integration settings with domain url fixed the issue.